# Ubuntu server 12.04 on XenServer 5.5 - Won't boot from iso

Tags: ubuntu, xenserver, citrix

I can't get the Ubuntu server 12.04 ISO to boot in XenServer 5.5.

It is not a problem with the ISO or the share because I have used the iso to install locally and I can install other ISOs from the same share.

I imagine it has something to do with the template because one isnt installed for this version of ubuntu. I am creating the VM using "Other install media" as the template.

Comment: What error are you getting? Have you installed the Linux pack?

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors (unless I'm looking in the wrong spot). It just shutsdown after printing "Initializing gfx code..." or sometimes it stops at the step before when it prints "Loading bootlogo..."

Comment: Have you installed the Linux Support / Supplemental pack?

Comment: No, I didn't know about the Linux pack. I'm not sure if a person before me installed that. I do have ubuntu 4 running currently on the server.

Comment: I don't have a XenServer near by, but try running "xe host-list params=all" on the console. If the Linux Pack is installed, it should show up, though I'm not 100% convinced it's your issue, it's a good first step. I think it shows up as "package-linux: installed"

Comment: Looks like the linux package is installed.

Comment: Good stuff - I'd head to @boburob's answer, then!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zeal, what I have done to get virtual Ubuntu hosts is to first follow the steps on this [website](http://community.citrix.com/display/xs/Installing+Ubuntu+Server+10.04+%2832bit+and+64bit%29+LTS). This will give you an Ubuntu 10.04 Template, I then used this template with newer version's of Ubuntu server via an ISO. Although you may be best to just run 10.04 to avoid any complications which may crop up in the future.

I also thought it might be worth mentioning to you one of the main issues I find with Ubuntu machines running in XenServer; [Rebooting a hung HVM in XenServer](http://majentis.com/2011/03/07/rebooting-a-hung-hvm-in-xenserver/).

Comment: Seems the Citrix website no longer has the article :( But archive.org to the rescue! https://web.archive.org/web/20110604063731/http://community.citrix.com/display/xs/Installing+Ubuntu+Server+10.04+(32bit+and+64bit)+LTS ... so far the process seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Press F6 at the ISO's grub menu (Before selecting 'Install Ubuntu Server') for extra boot options

Select ACPI=OFF

Comment: Solved it for me!